# Does persistent homology really make sense for mixed variable types?

Tags: mixed-type-data, topological-data-analysis

## Purpose

[Persistent homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_homology) is a fascinating approach to exploring data (see [Chazal & Michel 2021](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frai.2021.667963/full) for an introduction). I have seen many impressive examples of it through [AATRN](https://www.aatrn.net/). I'm considering how it can be used in my current and future projects. I am finding it confusing to consider the examination of persistence diagrams (e.g. [Marchese 2017](https://trace.tennessee.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5785&context=utk_graddiss)) of different types of [measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement).

To help avoid an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), I want to first insist that this question really is about how to usefully apply persistent homology to [experimental data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_data). Experimental data very often involves mixed types of variables. Standardization can be used to remove units, but I have vague worry that the variables are still of incompatible 'types'. By 'type' I am not referring to [level of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement) (i.e. [Steven's typology](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.103.2684.677), or [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) [invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)) more broadly). Rather the resulting standardized variables are still [monotonic functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonotonicFunction.html) of quantities that don't always feel like they should have a notion of proximity (e.g. X = number of people cringing in an audience, Y = [short-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) [dominant frequency](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0103.pdf) of sound coming from a trumpet playing [The Ecstacy of Gold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYI09PMNazw)) even if it can be mathematically constructed.

The following is an example that is intended to illustrate how disparate the meaning of experimental variables can have, but it can be skipped if the reader finds it tedious.

---

## A (Long) Example

Let me exemplify with a hypothetical, but not extremely unrealistic, scenario. I am going to make it rather more detailed than "here is my table of variables" because I want to emphasize to the reader that there is a lot of operational meaning behind each measurement. There is a lot of context behind each number in the data.

Suppose we have an unknown [microorganism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microorganism) in a glass vial containing a [thioglycolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thioglycolate_broth) [tryptic soy broth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tryptic_soy_broth). We might observe that the organism prefers to grow a different depths of the vial (depending on their optimal oxygen level for growth). Some of the possibilities are nicely shown below as five vials in which different populations of microbes growth optimally at different depths in a broth.

[image]

Wikipedia classifies these vials as the followed:

1. [obligate aerobes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obligate_aerobe)
2. [obligate anearobes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obligate_anaerobe)
3. [facultative anaerobes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facultative_anaerobic_organism)
4. [microaerophiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microaerophile)
5. [aerotolerant organisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerotolerant_anaerobe)

We will take our first variable to be aliquots taken from different depths of the vial recorded in millimetres. The volume of the aliquots are equally 100 microlitres, but are [serially diluted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_dilution) (perhaps logarithmically as shown below) for the following step.

[image]

At this point we have prepared some freshly [autoclaved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoclave) [tryptic soy agar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trypticase_soy_agar). The autoclaving was performed at some fixed temperature, pressure, and duration for each sample.

[image]

As the agar cools, but before it solidifies, we spike distinct concentrations of [maltose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltose) using a [syringe filter](https://www.fishersci.ca/ca/en/products/I9C8L6PM/syringe-filters.html).

[image]

[image]

Then we add the dilutions of microbial broth and liquid agar to plates, allow them to incubate for 24 hours, and then examine the plates.

[image]

Finally, the [colony-forming units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colony-forming_unit) are counted.

[image]

Tabulating the non-[degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution) variables, we have:

| Aliquot Depth | Dilution Factor | Maltose Spike Concentration | CFU Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The aliquot depth is in units of distance (e.g. mm). The dilution factor is dimensionless. The maltose spike concentration is likely units of [molar concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration). The CFU count is dimensionless, or if preferred: CFU's.

This process gives a data set where it isn't clear that a metric could be applied on the variables. [Standardizing the scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) would yield unit-less variables with more comparable centers and scale. But (1) it isn't clear whether the original scale might have been important and (2) such scores are still representing disparate types of quantities even if they are rendered unit-less.

In contrast, if we had collected the spatial cordinates of each colony in the agar plates, it seems natural to me to use a metric to compute how far each colony was from each other colony. And with this distance matrix, compute the persistence of each hole among the colonies.

---

## Question

Does it make sense to apply persistent homology to variables that, in an experimental context, mean very different things? If so, how?

---

Apologies for the imprecision of this question. There is just something about this approach that has a "[bad smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)" when it comes to mixed variable types. I am hoping someone can see the problem I can't seem to put into words.